# SIM card is not working on Sony Xperia Z (Android 4.1.2)

Tags: sim-card

My friend has a problem using his micro-SIM card on his new Sony Xperia Z (Android 4.1.2)

The problem is: when he inserts the SIM card, the phone display a message that the SIM card has been inserted, and restarts... then after the restart, displays 'SIM card removed' and restarts!

Notes:
1-The SIM card works perfectly on other phones.
2-The shop where he bought the phone has installed apps (mostly games) before he received it.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you take a look at the SIM and phone SIM socket if they are oxidized/dirty/greasy?
   If that is the case, you can clean it with a cotton cloth dipped in ethylene alcohol.
2. If the SIM socket pins are somehow are pushed down, that could be also an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing or more like adding a piece of paper on top of the Sim card! Else, try to contact the company. If you have installed the ROM your self, I mean by rooting and getting a new ROM. Then you might be in an issue! As there are many ROMS that have slight issues. Try going to that forum again from where you got the rom and contact the person who provided.

I read its Sony, so why not use a ROM made by Sony? Sony ROMs wont have an issue at all!

Answer (score 0):

Check that he is using a micro sim card and not a nano  sim with adapter. The poles are different size. Nano won't work  for z2. Maybe it's the same here.